# GCM prevent other app's from receiving Android messages

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions

So according to this documentation - https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html - one of the manifest requirements/entry is this:

> An applicationPackage + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" permission to
>   prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving the
>   Android application's messages. The permission name must exactly match
>   this pattern—otherwise the Android application will not receive the
>   messages.

So given that my manifest has no intent filter using this permission string or a `sendBroadcast()` that uses this string as the second parameter, how does it actually work ? I mean how does this piece of code:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

prevents any other app from receiving push notifications of this particular app ?

Comment: "how does it actually work ?" -- AFAIK, it does not work. If you remove those lines, you still get the GCM messages, in a light experiment I did a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Then why do they have that in the sample code and specify the prevention part in the docs ? Infact I really want to know howcome when I have 2 apps with similar broadcast receivers and intent-filters, why the correct app receives the push notification but not both of them ? I posted a question along this line yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/q/27316455/1437328

Comment: "Then why do they have that in the sample code and specify the prevention part in the docs ? " -- beats me. "why the correct app receives the push notification but not both of them " -- I assume and hope that Play Services uses an explicit `Intent` to deliver the message to you. It presumably has a mapping of registration ID to package name, which it uses to identify which app should get the broadcast. However, since this is all proprietary, we have no good way of knowing the precise implementation.

Comment: I get you. This leads to another interesting question I think which is, is it possible to explicitly mention the package name while sending a broadcast to a specific intent-filter action ?

Comment: "is it possible to explicitly mention the package name while sending a broadcast to a specific intent-filter action ?" -- you can make the implicit `Intent` be explicit by finding the specific component you want to talk to through `PackageManager`, then attaching the `ComponentName` to the formerly-implicit `Intent` to make it explicit. I haven't done this with broadcasts yet, but I have with activities and services. It's how the home screen triggers your specific `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activity when the user taps on your icon, for example.